# Next row or id gets deleted from table and database

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, delete-row

I have a table of chapters for which I have a delete button for each one. When I am clicking on delete button if the table has more records further the last row of the table gets deleted or the id of row getting pass to the database is wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Files</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="deleteFiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<style>
td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>

Select rank :
<select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 

<?php if(isset($_POST['type']))
{ ?>
<option value="1"  <?php echo($_POST['type']==1?"selected":"");?>>SSgt</option> 

<option value="2"  <?php echo($_POST['type']==2?"selected":"");?>>TSgt</option> 
<option value="3" <?php echo($_POST['type']==3?"selected":"");?>>MSgt</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<?php
}
    else 
    {
    ?>
    <option value="1">SSgt</option> 
<option value="2">TSgt</option> 
<option value="3">MSgt</option> 
</select>
<br><br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

<table id="example" style="width:60%">
    <tr>
    <th><font size="5">Files</font></th>
  </tr>

<?php



?>

<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(1); 
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); 

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=174;dbname=airman', 'airman', 'airma'); 


if(isset($_POST['action'])) {


     $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `files` WHERE `id`= " . $_POST['id']); 

    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        if(count($result) > 0)
        {
          echo 'row deleted';
        }
        else{
            echo 'row could not delete';    
        }
    }


if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM files where type = :type"); 
    $stmt->bindParam("type", $_POST['type']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
    else{
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM files"); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

    foreach($results as $file)

    {
    ?>
     <tr>
    <td><?php echo $file['title'];?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="<?php echo $file['id']?>" name="action" value="Delete">
        <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $chap['id']?>" name="edit"  value="Edit">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $file['id']?>" />

  </tr> 
    <?php
}
?>
</table>

</body>

</form>
</html>
<?php
?>
```

EDIT:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Files</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#form').submit(function(ev) {

        $('<input type="hidden">').attr({ name: 'type', value: $("select[name='type']").val() }).appendTo($(event.currentTarget));
    }

    </script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="deleteVideoFiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<style>
td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>


    <br><br><br><br>
Select rank :
<select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()">

<?php if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
  /*  session_start();

    $_SESSION['vidType'] = $_POST['type'];*/

    ?>
    <option value="">Select rank...</option>
    <option value="1"  <?php echo($_POST['type']==1?"selected":"");?>>SSgt</option>

    <option value="2"  <?php echo($_POST['type']==2?"selected":"");?>>TSgt</option>
    <option value="3" <?php echo($_POST['type']==3?"selected":"");?>>MSgt</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <?php
}
else
{
/*    session_start();

    $_SESSION['vidType'] = $_POST['type'];*/

    ?>
    <option value="">Select rank...</option>
    <option value="1">SSgt</option>
    <option value="2">TSgt</option>
    <option value="3">MSgt</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <?php
}
    ?>

<table id="example" style="width:80%">
    <tr>
        <th><font size="5">Video Files</font></th>
    </tr>

    <?php

    ?>

    <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=174.75.54;dbname=handbook', 'airman', 'airman12345');
  //  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=handbook', 'siddhi', 'siddhi');

    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `id`= :id");
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $_POST['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($result) < 0)
        {
            echo 'row could not delete';
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['type']))
    {

        if(!empty($_POST['type']))

        {

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `videos` where type = :type");
            $stmt->bindParam("type", $_POST['type']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($results) == 0)
            {
                echo 'No records available.';
            }
        }
        else{

            echo 'empty type';
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `videos`");
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($results) == 0)
            {
                echo 'No records available.';
            }

        }
    }
  /*  elseif(!empty($_SESSION['vidType'])){

        echo $_SESSION['vidType'];
        echo $_POST['type'];

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `videos` where type = :type");
            $stmt->bindParam("type", $_SESSION['vidType']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($results) == 0)
            {
                echo 'No records available.';
            }
    }*/

    else{

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `videos`");
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($results) == 0)
            {
                echo 'No records available.';
            }
    }
    foreach($results as $file)

    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $file['title'];?></td>
            <td>
          <form method="post" action="deleteVideoFiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $file['id']?>" name="action" value="Delete"><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $file['id']?>"/>
             </form> <!-- notice how we built different form for every id-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>

</body>

</form>
</html>
<?php
?>
```

I am sending the id of chapter in for each loop, What is the problem here? Please help thank you..

Comment: what is the value of `$_POST['id']`?

Comment: As I know id from <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $file['id']?>" name="action" value="Delete"> this input will go in $_POST_['id'].@NishantNair

Comment: @Sid then what is <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $file['id']?>" /> in your code?

Comment: I checked on some post to add hidden input for deleting a row. @SailiJaguste

Comment: @Sid The NAME of the input element is the important attribute as NAME is  transferred to the server, and not ID. So $_POST['id'] won't work for id = "value". You need to set name = "value"

Comment: if I want to check isset the id then how to check? _POST['name'] @SailiJaguste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because building the form element this way is going to result for many `id` inputs inside the same form. something like this

```
<form>
    <input name="id" value="1">
    <input name="id" value="2">
</form>
```

on your server code the php will set `$_POST['id']` to the last one which in this case `2`. that is why when press delete button and submit the form you delete the next , or *last* id you have built in your form

If you need your code work the way you want you have to put every id in different form element, Or you will need some javascript work.

I prefer building different form for each record. replace that code

```
foreach($results as $file)
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $file['title'];?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="<?php echo $file['id']?>" name="action" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $chap['id']?>" name="edit"  value="Edit">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $file['id']?>" />
</tr> 
<?php
    }
?>
```

with something like this

```
foreach($results as $file)
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $file['title'];?></td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="deleteFiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $file['id']?>" name="action" value="Delete">
            <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $chap['id']?>" name="edit"  value="Edit">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $file['id']?>" />
        </form> <!-- notice how we built different form for every id-->
    </td>
</tr> 
<?php
    }
?>
```

*Another note :*

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `files` WHERE `id`= " . $_POST['id']);
```

*using prepared statements this way makes you still vulnerable to SQL injection.*

---

**EDIT(reaction to comments)**
to send another input along with the delete forms to the PHP server. you can  use JavaScript for that.

1- add that class `deleteForm` to the delete forms so we can catch those forms and bind to only them.

```
<form method="post" class="deleteForm" action="deleteVideoFiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2- edit that script tag in your document

```
<script>
    $(function (){
        $('form.deleteForm').submit(function(ev) {
            $('<input type="hidden">').attr({ name: 'type', value: $("select[name='type']").val() }).appendTo($(ev.currentTarget));
        });
    })

</script>
```

Comment: how should be the query to avoid sql injection?

Comment: `DELETE FROM files WHERE id= ?` then bind the parameter with it's value, as you did in your code `SELECT * FROM files where type = :type`

Comment: hello are you there?@Accountant م

Comment: For this answer as I have added form for delete button, and the form redirects to the same page after delete is clicked so I have _POST['type'] according to that I am showing option as selected if chosen once but if delete the row that _POST['type']; field gets refresh as another form starts. I dont want that. what can be done? @Accountant م

Comment: @Sid  with javascript and jQuery you can add that input element to the form before it is submitted . add this code to the forms `submit` event listener `$('<input type="hidden">').attr({
 name: 'type',
    value: $("select[name='type']").val()
}).appendTo($(event.currentTarget));`

Comment: Before submitted?Sorry I did not get this.@ Accountant

Comment: the [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit)  is fired when a form is submitted. you can bind the code I give you in the comment to the `submit` event listener. for example `$("form").submit(function (){/*put here the code I give you in the comment*/});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141346/discussion-between-sid-and-accountant-).

Comment: @Sid forgive me, I can't chat right now. just try the code i give you and put it with your other JavaScript code

Comment: I tried this,
can u please check the edited question?
when I select any type and then delete the question it goes to else part of isset(_POST['type']) and displays all videos I want to display the same type videos after deleting the record. @Accountant م

Comment: still its not working, all videos shown again. @Accountant م

Comment: @Sid sorry the code braces was wrong, I edited the code, **check the edited code  again**.  and open your browser console to see which errors do you get

Comment: @Sid you are welcome :)  . that feeling what makes programming like drugs. congratulations it worked.